# Batch processing of large excel files timeout on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, architecture

**Context:**
I have an excel files in an S3 bucket. The excel files has approximately 1 million of records. Currently we have a worker(EC2) that's listening for S3 notification. Once it gets a notification it retrieve the files from the S3 bucket. The worker read the files record by record. For each record it affects multiple tables found in an SQL databases.

**Problem:**
Its timing out

**Question:**
How can we improve the existing architecture for it to be able to process those records efficiently without timing out?

Comment: IHostedService describe something runned in background. You run it. You await/pull some result from database/endpoint/metrics/other outputs. You assert. You stop running it - thats how.

Comment: I have updated the questions with more info.

Comment: Timeout can be in different places. Which particular place does it time out?